# Migrating datas to Firebase from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I am not quite getting the idea of `firebase`.

**My Current Scenario:**

Having a Web app that uses - `PHP` and `Mysql`

**Requirement:**

Creating a **Hybrid Mobile App** using `Ionic Framework` and learning that was a piece of cake since I already know `AngularJS`

Now here comes the hard Part:

I want the datas to get `sync` between mobile app and web app. After a lot of googling I cam around two ideas:

1) **Using Firebase** or 2) **Using PouchDB**

**Difficulties Faced:**

If I have to use `PouchDB` then I would have to use `CouchDB` in the server which is quite difficult I suppose replacing the existing `mysql`.

So, Using firebase, I have to import all my `DB` datas to Firebase and use a `javascript firebase Client` for synchronising

**So my Question is:**

**1)** After importing datas to firebase, If any further operations occurs in `mysql database` how the firebase will know of my changes? Because, my `PHP` scripts connect to the existing `mysql` database.??

**2)** Do I have to change my `PHP` scripts too?

Comment: Did my answer help you, or you may need some more help? If so, don't hesitate to ask, or mark it as correct if it, indeed, helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know - once you would do the switch to use Firebase (so, you would port all your existing data to Firebase), then all the further communication would be with Firebase itself - you would not need your MySQL database anymore.

Also, you wouldn't have to be using your PHP scripts anymore because you can do all the manipulation with firebase via your controllers in Angular.