# Can I use Firebase in my simple java crud operations?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crud

Can I use firebase - database to replace my xampp? As to use my crud operations online? I'm trying to make an android app and making the desktop as the server to make the crud operations for the android app.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this on SuperUser instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can. But remember firebase is not feature rich   as mysql or other relational databases. Further you can read following answers.

[Migrating datas to Firebase from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716802/migrating-datas-to-firebase-from-mysql)

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/firebase-talk/hpDsgc3-8OY

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Firebase, but what is rationale behind selecting Firebase?

Comment: im researching on how to make an android app then the tutorial on android studio used the firebase as its database..so im trying to use this on my thesis title mobile voting system using an android application so the voting can be online..